# Facebook (#32) Page request limited reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the following error while I am trying to access my page using Facebook Graph API.

```
{
error: {
message: "(#32) Page request limited reached",
type: "OAuthException", 
code: 32,
fbtrace_id: "F6d20m1iihx"
```

}
}

Could not find anything in Facebook API Documentation. Is this related to my API or page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Answer (score 30):

**It is related to your Page**. An App limit reached message error would have the code error 4.

Since July 11, 2016 Facebook has "improved" the Facebook Graph API rate limit **for page**.

## What's my current rate limit?

---

Now your **current rate limit** (current 24-hour window) is calculated using last 24-hour window number of engaged users.

Engagement includes **a click on the Page or Page content**.

**NOTE**: You can get this value with the [Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/insights) **page_engaged_users** metric.

## What's my current rate?

---

Your **current rate** is calculated by using:

- **Call count**
- **Total time used**
- **CPU time used**

You can check you current rate compared to your current rate limit on **your page** > **Insights** > **API** section:

```
https://www.facebook.com/<your-page-name>/insights/?section=navAPI
```

## What's my current "Call count" limit?

---

You can make **4800 calls for each engaged user** during a 24-hour period.

## What can I do?

---

1. **Wait to get more fans** to be able to get a higher rate limit.
2. Each Facebook Graph API response includes a **X-Page-Usage** header with *call_count*, *total_cputime* and *total_time* percentage  values (There is no header if the Page's utilization is effectively 0%). When any of these metrics exceed 100, the app managing that page will be rate limited. **Use that values to evaluate your API usage** so you can balance it and never get blocked. Example of page utilization header:

   ```
   X-Page-Usage : {'call_count' : 85, 'total_cputime' : 56, 'total_time' : 60}
   ```
3. If you still need a higher rate limit, consider **requesting a rate limit increase**.

   - Go to your App (not Page) dashboard:

     ```
     https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<your-api-ID>/dashboard/
     ```
   - Scroll down to the last block called "API limit at page level".
   - Select you page in the combobox.
   - Click on the "API Limit Increase Request" button. You'll be requested to fill a form including the reason for your app to reach the rate limit and why your app needs a higher rate limit.

## Detailed information

---

For more information, please see:

- [Improving Rate Limits for Page Management Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/06/16/page-level-rate-limits/) developers announcement.
- [API Graph Rate Limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) advanced documentation.

Comment: Always check the Facebook documentation for current information: rate limits can and do change without notice (as many experienced when Instagram dropped from 5000 to 200 on Mar. 30, 2019). Also be aware that the documentation may contain errors: as of 2019-10-11, only `total_cputime` and `total_time` are documented as to their limits.