# HTTP Header & Expiration Time for Facebook (#32) Page request limited reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

This post would be a follow-up question based on the [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872402/facebook-32-page-request-limited-reached).

I want to know details about the Facebook Graph API response X-Page-Usage header.

```
X-Page-Usage : {'call_count' : 85, 'total_cputime' : 56, 'total_time' : 60}
```

Since this X-Page-Usage header describes the API usage during the current 24-hour window. (So the time window period is the previous 24-hour, right?)

Here is my question, what if I received a rate-limit error with below response header (notice the call_count reaches the limit now):

```
X-Page-Usage : {'call_count' : 100, 'total_cputime' : 56, 'total_time' : 60}
```

And now I want to estimate an expiration peroid for the current rate-limit. But based on the current metric, it makes me confusing that 'total_time' = 60%, since it is the last 24 hours, why not the 'total_time' always be 100%?

Comment: Your app has gotten a certain amount of CPU time and “total time” (whatever that metric actually is) assigned, and those numbers show the percentage of that which you have already used. These values are _not_ related to the 24 hour window in a way that you could calculate any expiration time or anything like that from them.

Comment: Thanks! @CBroe Is there a way we can calculate the expiration time for Facebook rate limit error? e.g. for the other API like Twitter, we can get the remaining time in the time window in the header.

Comment: No, there isn't. You can only wait and retry later.